# Text inside div is splitting

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, angular

I tried many things this issue took almost my 5 hours. but I couldn't solve it.

This my page which has issue.

[Issue page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JkQM.png)

**Long text field 4:** and **Long text field 6:** are wrong. They should be align like **field 1 or 2 or 3 or 5.**

When I tried white-space:nowrap;

it isn't fixed.The texts went behind the button.

[After tried no wrap issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIRPN.png)

I am using external css(external css like (forexample abc (div class="abc")) for each label + button combination.

When I remove it. It is okey, it means this.
[Correct Design I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoVx6.png)

But I must add this external css to div because of the some reasons. What should I do fix it. Please help.

```
<style> 
.main {
    margin: 0;
}

.left  {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.right {
    float:left;
    widith: 50%
}

</style>
 
 <div class="main  abc">  <!-- abc my external css I don't know what it is but I must add it-->
    <div class="left">
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Field1" ID="Field1">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button1" ID="Button1"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Field2" ID="Field2">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button2" ID="Button2"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>  
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Field3" ID="Field3">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button3" ID="Button3"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>              
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="right">
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Long Text Field4" ID="Field1">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button4" ID="Button4"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Field5" ID="Field5">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button5" ID="Button5"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>  
        <FormElement>
            <MyRow>
                <FormRow>
                    <ExampleLabel>
                        <Label Text="Long Text Field6" ID="Field6">
                    </ExampleLabel>
                    <ExampleButton>
                        <MyButton Text="Button6" ID="Button6"/>
                    </ExampleButton>
                </FormRow>
            </MyRow>
        </FormElement>              
    </div>
```

If this code runs, the output will be first image I shared.

If I add .abc { white-space:nowrap; } to style part , the output will be image 2.

If I remove abc It means  the output will be I want

Comment: Please provide the full code, so we can modify it.

Comment: I am preparing it is too long I must change variable names etc. Alan one minute

Comment: Okey I shared I must change somethings so It takes long time Alan

Comment: Most of your tags are not HTML. From where did you get them? Please refer to the HTML specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ for all valid HTML tags.

Comment: they are from ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration; solving layout and alignment issues can be quite challenging at times. Let me try to assist you.
To address the issue you've described, you should ensure that each element (label, input, and button) within your divs with the class "abc" is aligned correctly. Here's what you can do:

```
<div class="abc">
    <label for="campo1">Campo 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="campo1" name="campo1">
    <button type="button">Pulsante 1</button>
</div>

<div class="abc">
    <label for="campo2">Campo 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="campo2" name="campo2">
    <button type="button">Pulsante 2</button>
</div>
```

And your external CSS might look like this:

```
.abc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between sections */
}

label {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 10px; /* Add space between the label and the input */
}
```

With this CSS, text fields and buttons should align correctly within each .abc section. Also, I added the bottom margin to separate the different sections vertically. I hope this can inspire you for your own solution.

Comment: I am trying dave, jesus must be send you to me. One minute I am trying my friend

Comment: It isn't fixed. The result like this Field 1: Field 2: Field 3: .... and buttons1 buttons2 ... (buttons  under texts)

Comment: Field1: Field2: Field3: Field4: Field5: Field6:
Button1: Button2: Button3: Button4: Button5: Button6:

Comment: let's try this way:

Html:
<div class="abc">
    <label for="campo1">Campo 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="campo1" name="campo1">
    <button type="button">Pulsante 1</button>
</div>

<div class="abc">
    <label for="campo2">Campo 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="campo2" name="campo2">
    <button type="button">Pulsante 2</button>
</div>

Comment: CSS:
.abc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add spacing between sections */
}

label, input, button {
    margin-right: 10px; /* Add space between elements */
}

/* Optional: To create space between the label and input */
label {
    flex-basis: 100px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
}